# How can I populate a dynamic two dimensional array in a for loop

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql5, metatrader5

This might seem trivial to many but it seems to be getting the better of me as I've not been able to figure out how to use the `ArrayResize()` (which I believe is very necessary) to solve this.

In the code below I want to populate `ar[][2]` when `isBody` is `true`. How can I achieve this.

```
int ar[][2];

void CheckBody()   {

   for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {
   
      if (isBody) {
         int a = i + 1;
         int b = i - 3*i;
         
         // how to populate ar with [a,b] when isBody is true in this block
         
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, it's programmed to run as an EA but can easily be modified if used in an indicator (you will have to add your code for the `isBody` variable).

```
#property strict

int ar[][2];

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Initialization function of the expert                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
   ArrayInitialize(ar,NULL);
   ArrayResize(ar,1);
return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Deinitialization function of the expert                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{

}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| "Tick" event handler function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
   for(int i=20; i>=0; i--)
   {
      if(isBody)
      {
         if(ar[0][0]!=NULL) ArrayResize(ar,ArrayRange(ar,0)+1);
         int a=i+1;
         int b=i-3*i;
         ar[ArrayRange(ar,0)-1][0]=a; ar[ArrayRange(ar,0)-1][1]=b;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code and got a compiler error `’{’ - too many initializers` pointing to `int ar[1][2] = {NULL,NULL};` so I changed it to `int ar[1][2] = {NULL};` and that solved the error. After running the code I realised that the array size of `ar` is always 2 no matter the number of elements I add to the array.

Comment: I've edited my answer and it should hopefully work for you now

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been here for a while. Thanks.

Comment: the code you provided above works for `int`s but when I use `double`, the first pair of doubles gives me some trash value. I always get 4.243991582918676e-314 and 1.152034350044175e-309 for the first pair which is far from correct.

Comment: I think you need to post your code as a new question.